# Why is Airflow DAG not scheduled?

Tags: airflow-scheduler

The code below triggers the DAG at 12:37 when Airflow is started at 12:35 (on Tuesday).

But when I remove ",minutes=10" from the code, the run is not scheduled.
Why is it like this?

```
start_date = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC) \
                      - timedelta(days=7, minutes=10)
dag = DAG(default_args={'start_date': start_date},
          schedule_interval='37 12 * * tue', dag_id='test1')
task = PythonOperator(...)
dag >> task
```

The code variant without minutes:

```
start_date = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC) \
                      - timedelta(days=7)
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the start_date without minutes?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. As Airflow is "recreating" the DAG all the time, "now" is moving, see https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date
And this is why the job is not started.

So I defined a fixed start date (anything in the far past) and used the LatestOnlyOperator. This works.

```
start_date = datetime(2018, 9, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
dag = DAG(default_args={'start_date': start_date},
          schedule_interval='37 12 * * tue', dag_id='test1')
latest_only = LatestOnlyOperator(task_id='latest_only', dag=dag)
task = PythonOperator(...)
dag >> latest_only >> task
```